# Is there such a thing as an entirely empty website project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, iis, web

I'm looking at working my long-standing API to run on IIS rather than in a desktop app as it is now. Everything on the API is working so I'd rather not change too much if I don't have to. I know about the new Web API template in ASP.NET MVC 4 and I've worked with it, but I found that it didn't give me the control over everything that this particular project needs.

So my question is, is there any way to build an application for IIS that has something like an entry-point where I can just get a web request then use entirely my own code from there? Or do I have to build something that uses the Web API?

Comment: Are you sure IIS is the right fit? If you already have web requests being handled by your desktop app, a Windows Service might be an easier conversion.

Comment: I suspect it might be more involved. Websites tend to work in a request/response model where very little state is maintained between page load or button press. If your own application is designed in such a way that it's _mostly_ stateless and doesn't depend on `static` state too much, then it might be feasible. EDIT: Depending on how you intend to deploy or use it, perhaps an [XBAP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970060.aspx) or Silverlight application might be worthwhile to consider as they'll be more like a _traditional_ application running in the browser.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure of what you're asking, but if I understand correctly you need to create a business layer that has an api wrapper.  The api itself will act as the data layer and then you just have to create the presentation layer.  The business layer will be what you seem to be asking for, but you have to write it yourself  but like your api.  Once it's written you really shouldn't have to touch it much.

Comment: BTW, you probably want a web application project of some kind (File->New Project), and not a web site (File->New web site)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you'll want an ASP.NET handler.

How To Create an ASP.NET HTTP Handler by Using Visual C# .NET
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308001

You'll need to handle parsing the request and serializing the result yourself.  It's probably much better to create a web-api facade in front of your services than trying to do it manually.